# Fun/Frustration With Coding Coding Theory

Tags: matlab, coding-theory, mathematica

it's time for practical coding theory. I am trying to write a simple program that will detected if a given binary code word is "correct" or not. If it is not correct, I want to detect/correct (since its binary i guess these two are pretty much the same :) ) the error, find out where it is. It will be of length $63$. Below is the algorithm I am trying to apply:
given

H = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 & . & . & . &\alpha^{62} \\ 
1 & \alpha^3 & \alpha^6 & \alpha^9 & . & . & .\\ 
1 & \alpha^5 & \alpha^{10} & \alpha^{15} & . & . & . 
\end{bmatrix}
where

1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\   
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\
0\end{bmatrix} 
$\alpha$  = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0\\
0\end{bmatrix} 
and so on. Next I will find some $\dot c \in F_2^{63}$ such that $H \dot c ^T = 0$.
Now when given some codeword, say, $ \dot y $ with errors such that $\dot y = \dot c + e$ where $e$ is the error. I should find out how many errors (maximum 3) and where they/it are/is.
In order to achieve that below are the steps I have taken, 
since

$H \dot y^T = H( \dot c + e ) = He^T =$  \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ . \\.\\.
\end{bmatrix} $18$ x $1$ matrix = \begin{bmatrix}
z_1 \\ z_2 \\ z_3 
\end{bmatrix} $z_i , i = 1,2,3$ is $6$ bits and it is some power of $\alpha$.\
To be specific,
$z_1 = \alpha^i + \alpha^j + \alpha^k$

$z_2 = \alpha^{3i} + \alpha^{3j} + \alpha^{3k}$

$z_3 = \alpha^{5i} + \alpha^{5j} + \alpha^{5k}$

$1.$ If $z_1 = z_2 = z_3 = 0$ then we have no errors

$2.$ If $z_1 ~= 0, z_2 = z_1^3, z_3 = z_1^5$ then we have one error in $z_1$

My questions:

- Do i have to perform similar checks for the others too?
- How can I check if two or three errors occur?
- Is there any sample code with any of you gurus? Matlab or Mathematica would be super awesome. But ofcourse other languages can be suggested. Which is the best choice for me now? Mathematica or MATLAB? Thanks alot.

Comment: $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ appears to be the *syndrome*. For "How can I check if two or three errors occur?" try Peterson algorithm.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, do you mean this one, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm?  If so, isnt there a simpler way? It cant be that complicated.

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity. I wanted to mention [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code#Peterson.E2.80.93Gorenstein.E2.80.93Zierler_algorithm).

Comment: ahh, now this looks spot on. That with more, i get;
If $z_2z_1^2 = z_3 + (z_1^3  - z_2 )^2 / z_1$ Then we have two errors and their locations can also be found. Is there a simpler way to express this? the one for 3 errors is huge. Is there a more simpler way to express these. But thats no big issue anymore anyway. 
I want to see these things in action now :))). I want to test them. 
Let's take a break from coding theory and venture a little into coding practice, shall we :) ?

Comment: I suspect you doubled the use of "Coding" in the title of your question.

Comment: @Donda, You are mistaken. It was intentional, look closer.

Comment: Actually one more thing regarding this question, I am almost done with the code. In fact I am done, I just need to get mathematica to evaluate the last error control and location statements if someone can help, I will be more than glad to post the code, or portion of it that is giving me trouble since comments are rather too restricted to allow me post all the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rediscovering the decoding algorithms for Bose-Chaudhuri-Hocquenghem (BCH) codes. For double- and triple- error-correcting codes, people have worked simpler algorithms that do not require matrix inversion as the Peterson algorithm that has been pointed out to you. See, for example, Polkinghorn, "Decoding of double and triple error correcting Bose-Chaudhuri codes, *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory,* October 1966, and van der Horst and Berger, "Complete decoding of triple-error-correcting binary BCH codes," *IEEE Transactions on Information Theory,* March 1976.

Comment: Ok, let me check these out now. For some reason i cant download the pdfs, does anyone have them, of do i need to use authority from a facility no matter what?

Comment: Actually one more thing regarding this question, I am almost done with the code. In fact I am done, I just need to get mathematica to evaluate the last error control and location statements if someone can help, I will be more than glad to post the code, or portion of it that is giving me trouble since comments are rather too restricted to allow me post all the code here.

Comment: If[z1 == 0 && z2 == 0 && z3 == 0, Print["No Errors"],
 If[z1 != 0 && z2 == (z1)^3 && z3 == (z1)^5, Print["1 error"]],
 If[z1 != 0 && z2*(z1)^2 == z3 + (((z1)^3 - z2)^2)/z1, 
  Print["2 errors occured"]; 
  Roots[x^2 + z1*x + (((z1)^3 - z2)/z1) x == 0, x], Print["3 errors"];
   Roots[x^3 + z1*x^2 + ((z2*(z1)^2 + z3)/(z2 + (z1)^3))*x + (z1)^3 + 
    z2 + z1*((z2*(z1)^2 + z3)/(z2 + (z1)^3)), x]]]

Comment: When the above code is run, say with $H\dot \dot y$, Instead of getting the results from if statements I get symbolic evaluations such as:
If[1 + w^2 + w^4 + w^5 != 0 && 
  w^3 (1 + w^2 + w^4 + w^5)^2 == 
   w^2 + w^3 + (-w^3 + (1 + w^2 + w^4 + w^5)^3)^2/(
    1 + w^2 + w^4 + w^5), Print["2 errors occured"]; 
 Roots[x^2 + z1 x + ((z1^3 - z2) x)/z1 == 0, x], Print["3 errors"]; 
 Roots[x^3 + z1 x^2 + ((z2 z1^2 + z3) x)/(z2 + z1^3) + z1^3 + z2 + (
   z1 (z2 z1^2 + z3))/(z2 + z1^3), x]]
and 
If[w + w^2 + w^3 + w^4 != 
   0 && (w + w^2 + w^3 + w^4)^2 (1 + w^2 + w^5) == 
   1 + w^4 ... 
Why ???

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic on math.SE for the most part. Try stackoverflow.SE or something similar instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. I will forward this to the mathematica forum then. But I actually treat this kind of programming more of mathematics than it is programming. At some poing i even considered separating mathematics from programming as crazy. Leaving the webprogramming and the likes out, ofcourse, but still. That was just a personal opinion. While here, I will obey the rules.
But I still think these sorts of problems are best understood and better solved by mathematicians, to the greatest extent at least. What do you think about that :) ?